# How to convert the whole html page in to an image with filled controls?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, webpage-screenshot

> Here the difficulty is that i also need the texts that has been filled by the user in html controls.

It will be appreciative if HTML5 or JavaScript is used.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like fun!

I would look into something like flash.

Or you could post the form back to a server and process it on the sever side to send the image back.

Check out this answer:

[Programatically create image from web-page or a single DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745467/programatically-create-image-from-web-page-or-a-single-div)

I can only assume you have access to PHP or something similar.

Comment: No, i don't want to post the form back to server side
i already seen your given link but that's not i want 
Actually i need this in C# not in php.
Check this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/58605/HTML-to-Image-in-C) I want to do like this but i want to with HTML5 canvas

Comment: Oh, you tagged your first post with javascript?

Comment: so what ? did i mistake ? i don't get you.